# How to get Ad id from Ad creative Facebook marketing API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-ads

I am using Facebook python business sdk for fetching Ad related data and the structure we have in database is identical to how facebook structured Ad related API. Following is the structure which was providing correct Ad creative objects

AdAccount -> Campaigns -> AdSet -> Ad -> AdCreative -> (Ad post id)

Now from previous 2-3 weeks there are some AdCreatives which are only available when fetched on Ad creative end-point via **Ad Account** and Ad id is not included in those I have two questions

-Can anyone help why some Ad creatives are missing when fetching on Ads and available on Ad accounts?

- How to get Ad id if ad creatives are fetched via Ad Account?

Comment: Hi! Could you share your code, please?

Comment: @Matteo the part where i am making call using facebook python business sdk ?

Comment: Basically some code that you're working on that you need help

Comment: @DaniyalSyed Have you got it working? How did you fetch Ad id from Ad creative?

Comment: did anyone find a way to get ad id from ad creative? @RohitSaini

Comment: did anyone find a solution? I can't figure out why some creatives only show on ad_account/adcreatives endpoint

Comment: I have same problem OMG!!!